# Prove that in $A$ with $m(A)>0$, $\exists x,y\in A$ s.t. $x\neq y$ and $x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: measure-theory, rational-numbers

I need help with this proof:

" Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set with $m(A)>0$. Prove that $\exists x,y\in A$ which verify that $x\neq y$ and $x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$"

At first i think about using that, given any two real numbers $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ ($a<b$), then $\exists q \in\mathbb{Q}$ so that $a<q<b$, but i'm sure if it's the right way.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Vitali sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set#Construction_and_proof)?

Comment: Not so much. Is It useful for this excersice? It's mentioned in my textbook but i haven't worked on it yet.

Comment: Yes, it essentially answers the question for you if you think about it right. If $A$ **doesn’t** have two elements that differ by a non-zero rational, it’s a Vitali set.

Comment: Thank you! I'll use that in my proof.

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I've been reading a bit about Vitali sets, and i'm not sure about one thing. Vitali sets are defined as non-measurable sets, but in my problem i'm assuming $A$ measurable. Does this make any problem or it just doesn't matter here?

Comment: That’s the whole point: your measurable $A$ cannot be a Vitali set, because they **aren’t** measurable. But then it must have ...

Comment: Oh ok now i see it. Thank you so much.

Comment: You’re very welcome.